# Initialize None multidimensional array

Tags: python

Let's say I have an array that is 10 x 100,000. What is the simplest and/or fastest way to initialize this? For example, something like:

```
[None,] * cols # now how to do it by # rows?
```

Comment: Something like numpy.full ((10,100000), None)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do this with vanilla Python lists, I would use a list comprehension:

```
big_array = [[None]*100000 for j in range(10)]
```

However, if you are going to be working with large arrays a lot, I would consider using using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
another_big_array = np.empty((10, 100000))
```

With numpy, be sure you get all 4 parentheses. np.empty() takes a single argument for the shape of the array, so for multidimensional arrays you need a tuple of integers, not multiple arguments.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The inner comprehension can be replaced with `[None]*100000` for a speed boost. (The outer comprehension **cannot** be replaced this way, or you'll have aliasing problems.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [numpy.full method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.full.html).

Example of a 2x2 array

```
 import numpy as np

 none_array = np.full((2, 2), None)
 print(none_array)
```